# Google Admob and WIndows 10 Universal Apps

Tags: admob, win-universal-app

Is there a way to use `Google AdMob` in `Windows 10` `Universal Apps`?

According to my reasearch no, but maybe someone here knows something I don't. I've tried using this tutorial https://developers.google.com/admob/wp/quick-start but it seems that in only works for `Windows Phone 8` (as stated there).

In microsoft ad mediation description it is openly stated that `AdMob` is not supported - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt219688.aspx.

So is there hope to utilize `Google AdMob` in `Windows 10` `Universal Apps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, Windows 10 isn't supported. You can follow the [official Windows Phone admob developers forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!categories/google-admob-ads-sdk/windows-phone-8) for updates on this.

Comment: this is not only currently but it isn't supported since windows phone 8.1 ... and thats y due to Admob we still developing apps for Windows Phon 8. :) disgusting

Answer (score 1):

You sould consider Smaato, that have released a SDK to W10, but I had success building to Windows 8.1 with admob, then it works on Windows Phone 10.

Comment: how you achieved for Windows 8.1 ?

Comment: I'm using smaato as a fallback ads provider, but it has 0.47% fillrate and 0.02 $ ECPM, so it's basically wothless.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Smaato in place of Admob for Windows Phones, but it's not the same quality you get with AM. Hopefully, they'll start supporting WP8.1 + soon.